Is there a way I can reuse a toggle function for a list of navigation items that have a drop down when clicked?
Here I have 3 addEventListeners that call a function when clicked to open a drop down menu according to which nav item is clicked.
My problem is once it the first menu item is clicked it opens and closes just fine but the rest of them do not work.
document.getElementById('product-menu').addEventListener('click', openMenu);
document.getElementById('company-menu').addEventListener('click', openMenu);
document.getElementById('connect-menu').addEventListener('click',openMenu);

function openMenu(){
    document.getElementById('dropdown-menu').classList.toggle('active')
};

I was trying to allow the reuse of the toggle function to open up the dropdown-menu on each nav item.
Here is the HTML requested to be attached to this.
 <li id="product-menu" class="dropdown">
      <a class="drop-item" href="#" >Product<img src="images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt=""/></a>
      <ul id="dropdown-menu" >
        <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MarketPlace</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Integrations</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li id="company-menu" class="dropdown"></li>
      <a class="drop-item" href="#">Company<img src="images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt=""/></a>
      <ul id="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MarketPlace</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Integrations</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li id="connect-menu" class="dropdown"></li>
      <a class="drop-item" href="#">Connect<img src="images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt=""/></a>
      <ul id="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MarketPlace</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Integrations</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>



document.getElementById('dropdown-menu'). note that an id MUST be unique on the document please share your HTML so we can best assist you here.  You might even only need ONE event listener here also if you delegate.

The HTML is invalid. You have an extra </li> on the same line as the 2nd and third <li>

Your HTML is invalid with duplicate <ul id="dropdown-menu"> ids  Ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

IDs have to be unique, you can't reuse id="dropdown-menu" in each submenu.
You should use a class, instead: <ul class="dropdown-menu">. Then in the listener function you can use
this.querySelector(".dropdown-menu").classList.toggle("active");

Full code:


document.querySelectorAll("li.dropdown").forEach(li => li.addEventListener("click", openMenu));

function openMenu() {
  this.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').classList.toggle('active')
};
ul.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

ul.dropdown-menu.active {
  display: block;
}
<ul>
  <li id="product-menu" class="dropdown">
    <a class="drop-item" href="#">Product<img src="images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt=""/></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MarketPlace</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Integrations</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li id="company-menu" class="dropdown">
    <a class="drop-item" href="#">Company<img src="images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt=""/></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MarketPlace</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Integrations</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li id="connect-menu" class="dropdown">
    <a class="drop-item" href="#">Connect<img src="images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt=""/></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MarketPlace</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Integrations</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>




That didnt work for me.  I will post my HTML

I updated the answer based on your HTML.

And also corrected the mistake I pointed out above.

Thank you very much, that was easier to implement then I thought.
